# ¿Es posible crear un archivo excel desde MS Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que estoy haciendo un programa en MS Visual Basic, por medio de el IDE Visual Studio 2017, donde se precisa generar un documento excel con cierto formato y con ciertas formulas en unas celdas establecidas, a traves de un botón que este desde un formulario en MS Visual Basic.
¿como podría hacerlo?, ¿podrían darme algún ejemplo?.

Answer (score 2):

Estoy seguro que te quedará clarísimo en el siguiente [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Export-DataTable-object-to-b3e2c1f0)